# Alamofire cache issue

Tags: ios, swift, caching, swift3, alamofire

I'm running into a problem with Alamofire where I'm getting the same response for a different request. I use the following method to request:

```
        self.ephemeralManager?.request("myurladdress.com", headers: headers)
            .authenticate(user: username, password: password)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
            }
```

Here is the SessionManager:

```
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        configuration.urlCache = nil
        ephemeralManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

When I make the request the first time it works as expected. When I make the request again shortly after, with a different username and password, I get the response data from the previous request. If I restart the app or if I wait a while, the request works as expected.

I assume this is a caching issue but all attempts to clear the cache before I make the request or to turn off caching have failed.

Is there something that I'm missing? I have used Alamofire quite a bit and have never run into this issue.

Alamofire version: 4.1
Xcode version: 8.3.3 
Swift version: 3.1
Platform(s) running Alamofire: iOS
macOS version running Xcode: 10.12.5

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the cache before making the alamofire request.

```
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
```

after executing this command then call alamofire request.

Comment: It is not working for me. I had tried that before, but I did it again and no luck.